# Restangular update call when options change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, restangular

My services.js

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
factory('MyApi', function (Restangular) {

    var options = {quran: 210, content: 217, audio: 1};
    var callBack = 1;
    return {
        option: {
            quran: Restangular.all("options").one("quran").getList(),
            content: Restangular.all("options").one("content").getList(),
            audio: Restangular.all("options").one("audio").getList()
        },
        optionChange: function(key, value){
            // console.log(value)
            options[key] = value
            console.log(options)
            Restangular.all("bucket").one("page", 2).get(options).then(function(response){

                callBack = response
                console.log(callBack)
                console.log(this)
            });
            // console.log(this.call)



        },
        setOptions: options,
        call: callBack

    };
})
```

I am trying to get it such that whenever there is a change the optionChange function is called, changes the options for the Restangular function then it'd be pushed to my controller:

```
  .controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope, MyApi, Restangular, $routeParams) {


      console.log(MyApi.call)
      $scope.array = MyApi.call




    })
```

Answer (score 0):

At first your factory is returning nothin from option change, you have to return promise from restangular (callbacks are oldschool and not angular way of doing things.

```
 optionChange: function(key, value){
        options[key] = value
        return Restangular.all("bucket").one("page", 2).get(options);
 }
```

Then inside controller.

```
.controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope, MyApi, Restangular, $routeParams) {
       $scope.optionChange = function(key,value) {
           MyApi.optionChange(key,value).then(function(response) {
              $scope.array = response;
           });
       }
    });
```